# Include original post when sharing a link to a Facebook page

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-page

I want to share a post to a page's feed. I am using the `{page-id}/feed` endpoint. I make a POST request with `link={original-post-link}`. This works if the original post doesn't contain any links. Then the text of the original post is shared as expected. However, if the original post contains a link, only the link is shared. The text is not. When I try to share the original post from the website, I get the option "Include Original Post". Is there a way to do the same from the API?

Comment: Now the option "include original post" is broken on the website too.